# How to list out all the distros available in windows subsystem for Linux in windows using windows PowerShell?

Tags: linux, windows, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I installed the WSL form Microsoft store and the I have tried to get the list of distros using the below command.

wsl.exe --list --online

[image]

But I got the below error.

Failed to fetch the list distribution from 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/microsoft/WSL/master/distributions/DistributionInfo.json'. A connection with the server could not be established
Error code: Wsl/WININET_E_CANNOT_CONNECT

Answer (score 5):

On Windows 10, I am having this same issue.  I just performed wsl --update, so I am on the latest WSL 2.

I am finding that DNS Servers include 2 that are ipv6 addresses.

I can open https://raw.githubusercontent.com in my browser, and I can curl it from wsl command line, but from Windows Command Prompt, `wsl --install Ubuntu` fails with "Failed to fetch the list distribution".

I suspect it all has to do with the DNS Name resolinvg to an IPv6 address that curl and the browser can handle but the wsl subsystem cannot?

To test this I added an entry to my windows hosts file C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts, ie:
  `185.199.110.133  raw.githubusercontent.com`

and in a new Command Prompt Window, `wsl -l -o` works as expected, ie:

```
c:\> wsl -l -o
The following is a list of valid distributions that can be installed.
Install using 'wsl.exe --install <Distro>'.

NAME               FRIENDLY NAME
Ubuntu             Ubuntu
Debian             Debian GNU/Linux
kali-linux         Kali Linux Rolling
SLES-12            SUSE Linux Enterprise Server v12
SLES-15            SUSE Linux Enterprise Server v15
Ubuntu-18.04       Ubuntu 18.04 LTS
Ubuntu-20.04       Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Ubuntu-22.04       Ubuntu 22.04 LTS
OracleLinux_8_5    Oracle Linux 8.5
OracleLinux_7_9    Oracle Linux 7.9
```

Answer (score 2):

I am facing the same issue and I think it has something to do with IPv6 connectivity in Windows.

As `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/*` is IPv6 only.

```bash
curl google.com
```

works but

```bash
curl raw.githubusercontent.com
```

doesn't.

As a workaround to this problem, you can enable Virtual Machine Platform through `Turn Windows Feautures On or Off` menu and install WSL2 and WSL distro of your choice from Microsoft Store.

Comment: My Virtual Machine Platform is turned on and I have wsl2 on my system, but still i am facing the same problem.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too. Changing my network connection resolved it for me.